# How to have multiple rows on the left side of an equation

Tags: equations, multirow

I have an equation whose left side has a long text. I would like to make it on multiple rows followed by the equal sign and then the right side.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{The left hand side of this equation is very long} = a < x < b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is what I want. The left side has two rows so that it's not too wide.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\parbox{4cm}{\raggedright The left hand side of this equation is very long}
```

replacing `4cm` by whatever length you need.

Comment: Is there an automatic way of specifying the width? Now I have to try a few times to get the correct width. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickLi not really, tex either sets text all in a line (line `\mbox` or line breaks it to a fixed with (like `parbox`) it is up to you to decide how much space to allocate to the text.